# Conditional sync with SymmetricDS

Tags: java, symmetricds

I've been trying to make a conditional sync with SymmetricDS. Problem is, no matter what I do it just ignores the table that is supposed to be synced conditionally and just syncs tables without conditions.

So I suppose, I use those conditions wrong. I couldn't find this material in User guide for current version, so I have the following:

```
insert into sym_router 
(router_id,source_node_group_id,target_node_group_id,router_type,router_expression,create_time,last_update_time)
values('corp_2_one_store', 'corp', 'store', 'column','STORE_ID=:EXTERNAL_ID or OLD_STORE_ID=:EXTERNAL_ID',current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

insert into sym_trigger_router 
(trigger_id,router_id,initial_load_order,initial_load_select,last_update_time,create_time)
values('item_selling_price','corp_2_one_store',100,'store_id=''$(externalId)''',current_timestamp,current_timestamp);
```

from samples packaged with SymmetricDS, but I changed "store" to "client" and "corp" to "server" in my own configs and it doesn't work anymore. And quite frankly, I have no idea what's going on here with `STORE_ID=:EXTERNAL_ID or OLD_STORE_ID=:EXTERNAL_ID` and `store_id=''$(externalId)''` and why there is two of them.

From the site I have from earlier versions this example:

```
insert into SYM_TRIGGER 
  (source_table_name, source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, channel_id, 
   sync_on_insert, sync_on_update, sync_on_delete,
   node_select, 
   initial_load_order, last_updated_by, last_updated_time, create_time)
values
  ('sale_transaction', 'corp', 'store', 'sale_transaction', 
   1, 1, 1, 
   'and external_id = $(curTriggerValue).store', 
   105, 'demo', current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
```

But this obviously doesn't work since half of this info is now stored in different place, but even removing colums that are not there anymore (who knows, maybe these new tables only store the same info for readability?) I can't get it to work.

Any suggestions?

**Update**
When I run just the training example everything works. So real question here is: what do these mean:
`STORE_ID=:EXTERNAL_ID or OLD_STORE_ID=:EXTERNAL_ID` and `store_id=''$(externalId)''`? And how can I change that if my nodes are called `server` instead of `corp` and `client` instead of `store`?

**Update 2** 
According to [this](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.7/html/user-guide.html#_column_match_router), my router is okay, and I have some problems with my `sym_trigger_router` configuration, namely, `store_id=''$(externalId)''`

Comment: What's the version of symmetricDs that you're using?

Comment: @BorisPavlović the latest, 3.7.19

Comment: The router seems fine, could you see if after inserting/updating a row in the db that is routed by this router there's a new row in `sym_outgoing_batch` table? This table can be joined with `sym_data_event` and `sym_data` to see which data belongs to a routed outgoing batch.

Comment: In `sym_data_event` I have two rows for common router and none for router, that is supposed to split data between different clients. So I suppose it means that my data is not routed

Comment: Yes, data hasn't been routed. Next suggestion is to enable logging of symmetricDs's sql statements and see if the router is really used.

Comment: @BorisPavlović but if that helps, I have three data_events, that have `?` as router and they were in `outgoing_batches` to my client node (I just left one for testing purpuses) in `reload` channel

Comment: Sorry, but can't understand the last comment.

Comment: @BorisPavlović here is the extract from `select * from sym_data_event`: http://tinypic.com/r/jl5u36/8

Comment: getting it now, understand

Comment: @BorisPavlović I've got nothing, man :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found my problem. I had a typo in my table name, so no triggers were created for it.

For those, who somehow stumble upon this question:

1) what is `STORE_ID=:EXTERNAL_ID or OLD_STORE_ID=:EXTERNAL_ID`?

It's clearly written [here](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.7/html/user-guide.html#_router_types), but in two words, `STORE_ID` is a column name, `OLD_` means *previous value of the column* and `:EXTERNAL_ID` is one of SymmetricDS internal variables, along with `:NODE_ID` and so on.

This string is used to determine, whether to fetch current row or not and it is a parameter of the router. (If you decide to use router of another type, beware, it has other parameters, be diligent!)

2) what is `store_id=''$(externalId)''`

This is described to some point [here](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.7/html/user-guide.html#_trigger_router), but again, in two words: During initial load by default symmetric gathers all the data from the table (`select * from ...`). This parameter is what is appended to `where` clause and `t` can be used to reference the table that is being synced. `$(externalId)` is one of the variables, that SymmetricDS initializes during startup, there is a list of such variables somewhere in the User Guide.